# Managed Query is not defined for service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to get call logs with this code but I am getting error that `managedQuery` is not defined for service:

```
        private void getCallDetails() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append( "Call Details :");
        while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
        String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
        switch( dircode ) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        dir = "OUTGOING";
        break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        dir = "INCOMING";
        break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        dir = "MISSED";
        break;
        }
        sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        }
}
```

Is there any way to do it in a service class as I want to make it work in the service class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting error that managedQuery is not define for Service

`managedQuery()` is a deprecated method on `Activity`.

> Is there any way to do it in a service class as I want to make it work in the service class.

Call `query()` on a `ContentResolver`. You can get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on your `Service`. And, please call `query()` on a background thread, as it will involve disk I/O and IPC.

Comment: Please post the modified code I am not able to understand what is going on.